# How should I be investing money so I can make more (without restarting the whole game)?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Each player has about $55 Million, any tips on how to invest that so I can make more without restarting the whole game with the assassination missions in mind?

Comment: Manage money for what?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Oh, uh, for example, the golf course costs like 150 million.  I have 50 million.

Comment: I guess I'll probably get bored with the game before I can blow through 50 million, but I was just wondering if there was a semi-easy or fun way to earn a lot.  The nuclear waste collection has been pretty lucrative, but I guess to be, say, a billionaire, the only option IS to start over, and invest correctly in all the assassination missions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stocks. Invest a majority of your money in the Insurance stocks and spend your day blowing up all the cars. Once You've blown up a majority of the cities vehicles, check the stock and it will defiantly have increased. Sell and enjoy your quick cash.

Comment: oh interesting, that's a good idea.  I figured stocks were the only ways to get mega rich, but I didn't really know if I had to sit down and study them like I would real stocks.  I know Bawsaq is all player dependant.

Answer (score 1):

So I did some research and figured this out.

It's pretty simple, although it takes a bit of trial and error.

Before you invest your money, SAVE YOUR GAME. Save it in a slot that you won't touch in case the stock doesn't go up soon enough.

Get online and go to Bawsaq. Find the lowest down % Change, or one of them, with a low Current price. I picked HAL HawkandLittle at like 1.30 dollars with a -39.39% change (or close to that).

I spent ALL my money on it (50,000,000) and then went to sleep. Real sleep. I read that it can take 5 real time hours.

I checked again the next day and it was up 50%! I made 25Million!

No crap. I can't believe it was that easy, or maybe I got lucky. But I think the idea is when you find a super low priced stock, with extreme negative %Change, it's bound to go up on Bawsaq, which is player controlled.

Anyway, I spent an hour searching for this and thought I'd share it here, it may already be somewhere here. But mostly I've just found stock secrets that required you to start the game over using the assassination missions.

Comment: Udate.  I started with around 55,000,000 per character at the end of the game.  Using Bawsaq and specifically HawkandLittle (and once Ubermacht) I'm up to 200,000,000.  And that was buying and selling 3 times.  I just watched the markets and put all my money into the stock when it was at it's lowest (one example HawkandLittle when it was .80 sold when it was 2.10).  Sold at it's highest.  This is obvious and basic stock trading, but I did have to figure out which ones were the best bet.  Like I said, HawkandLittle and Ubermacht for me.